# Question about 'mysql error 1064'

Tags: mysql

```
ALTER TABLE sample62 CHANGE newcol c;
```

This code makes me mad. I just followed the book I had.

Program said

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
>   to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1.

My MySQL version is 5.7. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 3):

> mysql error 1064

The error that gets thrown if the syntax is wrong. You did not clearly state what you are doing.

If you are changing a column

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN column_name datatype
```

If you are trying to change column definition

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE old_column_name new_column_name data_type(size)
```

If you are adding a new column

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name datatype
```

Comment: What is "change column definition" as opposed to "changing a column"?

Comment: "change column definition" - this includes renaming the column and more stuffs.

Answer (score 2):

I believe MySQL requires the [`ALTER TABLE ... CHANGE ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html) statement to restate the column *definition* (datatype, default value, column constraints &c.) even if it's only the column name being changed.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your query like this:

```
ALTER TABLE database_name.sample62 CHANGE old_column_name new_column_name INT(11) DEFAULT 0 NULL;
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this syntax:

```
Alter table tablename CHANGE [COLUMN] old_col_name new_col_name column_definition
```